# How do I move a line of text in a file to the top if it contains a word (need for multiple files)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a file structure as follows:

```
folder\spkgbuild
folder2\spkgbuild
folder3\spkgbuild
```

each spkgbuild has the following:

```
name=packagename
version=1.0
release=1
# depends : packages
# description : blah blah

build()
{

}
```

I want to move # description to the top of the file and # depends under it, like this:

```
# description : blah blah
# depends : packages
name=packagename
version=1.0
release=1


build()
{

}
```

Any idea how?

Comment: can you use script for it? like python.

Comment: I don't care what language is used as long as it gets the job done lol. I used sed to fix my other problems with the files in here...but I am truly stumped at the moment.

Comment: okey so your files contain line that starts with `# description:` and line with `# depends:` and you want them to go up, is that all?

Comment: Yes just to the very top of the file. I have a "before" and "after" section in my original post.

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

And a far from robust Linux one-liner:

```
 find -type f -name spkgbuild -printf "%h\n" | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'cd $0 ; cat <(grep -xE "^# des.*" spkgbuild) <(grep -xE "^# dep.*" spkgbuild)  <(grep -xvE "^# de.*" spkgbuild) > spkgbuild.1;mv spkgbuild.1 spkgbuild'
```

Explanation:
Find all files named spkgbuild
Pass the directory each lives in to xargs, `cd` into each direcotry containing the file respectively, use three `grep`s to rearrange the lines, write the output to a temporary file (`spkgbuild.1`), `mv` that file to `spkgbuild` when done.

Comment: Description should come first, so first `grep` the description, next the depends and next the other lines.

Comment: OP says: `I want to move # description to the top of the file and # depends under it, like this:`.

Comment: RIght. Sorry, I missed that (and misunderstood your comment).  Fixing now.

Comment: Pleased to hear - feel free to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

there it is, i feel like a should be paied for this though

```py
filesToModify = ["add your path here", "and here", "and so on"]
linesToMove = ["# description :", "# depends :"] # you can add more

for fName in filesToModify:
    content = ""
    with open(fName, "r") as fl:
        lines = []
        for line in fl:
            moved = False
            for start in linesToMove:
                if line.startswith(start): 
                    lines.insert(0, line + ("\n" if not line.endswith("\n") else ""))
                    moved = True
                    break
            if not moved:
                lines.append(line)
        content = "".join(lines)
    with open(fName, "w") as fl:
        fl.write(content)
```

then run i like `python script.py`.

Comment: Needs optimization, edge-case guards, type-annotations, filename globbing, and a 20+ line `argparse` section including options for backups/copies/overwriting. 
(I jest, this looks like it will work well enough as written.)